# Replace whole tokens that may contain regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I want to do a startStr.replaceAll(searchStr, replaceStr) and I have two requirements.

1. The searchStr must be a whole word, meaning it must have a space, beginning of string or end of string character around it.

   - e.g.

     - startStr = "ON cONfirmation, put ON your hat"
     - searchStr = "ON"
     - replaceStr = ""
     - expected = " cONfirmation, put  your hat"
2. The searchStr may contain a regex pattern

   - e.g.

     - startStr = "remove this * thing"
     - searchStr = "*"
     - replaceStr = ""
     - expected = "remove this  thing"

For requirement 1, I've found that this works:

`startStr.replaceAll("\\b"+searchStr+"\\b",replaceStr)`

For requirement 2, I've found that this works:

`startStr.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(searchStr), replaceStr)`

But I can't get them to work together:

`startStr.replaceAll("\\b"+Pattern.quote(searchStr)+"\\b", replaceStr)`

Here is the simple test case that's failing

`startStr = "remove this * thing but not this*"`

`searchStr = "*"`

`replaceStr = ""`

`expected = "remove this  thing but not this*"`

`actual = "remove this * thing but not this*"`

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: But I should note that I had to make one additional change.
Using \s instead of \b eats up a character, so "ON ON".replaceAll("(\\s|^)ON(\\s|$)"," ") will only replace the first ON.
I ended up using replaceFirst() and looping to replace all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the \b, or word boundary, is not going to work for you with the asterisks.  The reason is that \b only detects boundaries of word characters.  A regex parser won't acknowledge * as a word character, so a wildcard-endowed word that begins or ends with a regex won't be surrounded by valid word boundaries.

Reference pages:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html

An option you might like is to supply wildcard permutations in a regex:

```
(?<=\s|^)(ON|\*N|O\*|\*)(?=\s|$)
```

Here's a Java example:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

class RegExTest
{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    String sourcestring = "ON cONfirmation, put * your hat";
    sourcestring = sourcestring.replaceAll("(?<=\\s|^)(ON|\\*N|O\\*|\\*)(?=\\s|$)","").replaceAll("  "," ").trim();
    System.out.println("sourcestring=["+sourcestring+"]");
  }
}
```

You can write a little function to generate the wildcard permutations automatically.  I admit I cheated a little with the spaces, but I don't think that was a requirement anyway.

Play with it online here: http://ideone.com/7uGfIS

Comment: Yeah, I read about word boundaries a bit. I was hoping for a simpler answer. This is probably the right answer. I'll wait a bit to see if anyone else has another solution, but will probably accept this as the right answer in the morning

Comment: Well, it certainly gets simpler, with just `(?<=\s|^)(ON|\*)(?=\s|$)` and no "permutation generation", if you don't need partial wildcards.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern `"\\b"` matches a word boundary, with a word character on one side and a non-word character on the other. `*` is not a word character, so `\\b\\*\\b` won't work. Look-behind and look-ahead match but do not consume patterns.  You can specify that the beginning of the string or whitespace must come before your pattern and that whitespace or the end of the string must follow:

```
startStr.replaceAll("(?<=^|\\s)"+Pattern.quote(searchStr)+"(?=\\s|$)", replaceStr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

For removing `"ON"`

```
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String[] splittedValue = startStr.split(" ");
        for (String value : splittedValue)
        {
            if (!value.equalsIgnoreCase("ON"))
            {
                stringBuilder.append(value);
                stringBuilder.append(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString().trim());
```

For removing `"*"`

```
    String startStr1 = "remove this * thing";
    System.out.println(startStr1.replaceAll("\\*[\\s]", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(^| )\*( |$)` instead of using `\\b`

Try this `startStr.replaceAll("(^| )youSearchString( |$)", replaceStr);`